# Configure POST ProtocolBinding in Spring Security SAML authentication request

Tags: spring, security, binding, saml, spring-saml

Spring Security SAML insists on requesting the Artifact binding in the SAML authentication request (ProtocolBinding attribute):

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                 AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://sp.com/saml/SSO/alias/defaultAlias"
                 Destination="https://idp.com/idp"
                 ForceAuthn="false"
                 ID="a4acj06d42fdc0d3494h859g3f7005c"
                 IsPassive="false"
                 IssueInstant="2012-12-05T17:07:18.271Z"
                 ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"
                 Version="2.0"
                 >
```

How can I configure POST binding instead?
Thanks for any answers!

-- Andreas

Answer (score 7):

Thanks nobby and Sanjeev, I've recently applied this to a similar case and it put me on the right track.

Being very new to the Spring Security SAML2 extension, I had to do a little extra digging around to get the WebSSOProfileOptions applied.  Essentially to get an HTTP-POST binding on the SAML authentication request you need the profile options passed to the `org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl#sendAuthenticationRequest()` method.

For our config, which is very similar to the [config in the Spring RC2 sample project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-saml/blob/master/saml2-sample/src/main/resources/security/securityContext.xml), this meant passing the `WebSSOProfileOptions` bean as described in Sanjeev's solution to the `samlEntryPoint.defaultProfileOptions` property (or adding a binding property there).

Trouble is, this did not result in the AuthnRequest picking up the binding property as set.  In our case our SAML metadata was specifying `isDefault=true` on the HTTP-Artifact bound `AssertionConsumerService`.  And in our RC2 version of the Spring Security SAML2 library this is the default behaviour of the `org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator`.

This can be overridden by setting the `assertionConsumerIndex` property of the MetadataGenerator.  The HTTP Post assertion consumer gets configured at index 1 in our case.

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
   <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
         <property name="assertionConsumerIndex" value="1" /><!-- 1=HTTP-POST -->
      </bean>
   </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: you are the man !!! your comment here answered precisely on the issue i was struggling with. thank you so much!

Comment: Index value of 1 works because the MetadataGenerator's default bindingsSSO list is "artifact", "post", "paos". Redefining bindingsSSO property so that "post" is first worked for me. `<property name="bindingsSSO"><list><value>POST</value>...</property>`

Answer (score 2):

In the `securityContext.xml` sp-initiated binding can be set. Example below used HTTP-POST

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
                <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
                <property name="binding" value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
            </bean>
```

Values of bindings can be found in `org.opensaml.common.xml.SAMLConstants` class.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to do it in Java rather than XML:

```
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileOptions profileOptions() {

    WebSSOProfileOptions profileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
    profileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
    profileOptions.setBinding(SAMLConstants.SAML2_POST_BINDING_URI);

    return profileOptions;
}
```

and:

```
@Bean
public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
    return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
}

public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
    MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
    metadataGenerator.setAssertionConsumerIndex(1);
    // ...
    return metadataGenerator;
}
```